# Edit another model after creating an instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am finding it difficult to achieve the following scenario:

In my app, a user creates a project, now to that project he can link a previous team that he created or create a new team.

A team can be part of many projects but a project is linked to only ONE team.

**models.py**:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = '')
    team_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name

class TeamMember(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    team_id = models.ForeignKey(Team, blank=True, null=True)
    project_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs = {'pk' : self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**:

```
class ProjectCreate(CreateView):
    model = Project
    fields = ['name']
    template_name = 'project_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.project_hr_admin = self.request.user
        return super(ProjectCreate, self).form_valid(form)

class ProjectDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'project_details.html'

class TeamCreate(CreateView):
    model = Team
    fields = ['team_name']
    template_name = 'team_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj2 = Project.team_id
        obj2 = obj.team_id
        obj2.save()
        print("sucess")
```

I would like that when a user creates a team, and if the team is created it successfully. Add automatically to the Project models with the corresponding `team_id`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to use model inheritance?

Comment: When a team is created you want to create a corresponding project? automatically?

Comment: No.. When a project is created the user is asked to give a name, the team_id is blank. then the user create a team.. and I want that when the team is created the team_id change from Blank to the ID of the team that has just been created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can get the project with your user id which has a team_id null.
In the `form_valid` method of your `TeamCreate()` view:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
     valid = super(TeamCreate, self).form_valid(form)
     obj = form.save()
     obj2 = Project.objects.get(project_hr_admin=self.request.user, team_id=None)
     obj2.team_id = obj
     obj2.save()
     return valid
```

Here you just get the Project which has your user as admin and a null team_id.

Warning though, if an admin create two projects with no team, the request `Project.objects.get(...)` will raise an error as it will return more than one object.

So you must be sure it will always be one project and then one team created.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thx for your answer but it raised an error :  raise FieldError('Related Field got invalid lookup: {}'.format(lookups[0]))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: is_null

Comment: can you try with ```team_id_id__is_null=True```?

Comment: I get the same : 
Exception Type: FieldError at /website/addteam/
Exception Value: Related Field got invalid lookup: is_null

Comment: ```team_id=None``` ?

Comment: I get website.models.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Project -- it returned 3!.. Don't you think that the issue is more with : project_hr_admin=self.request.user; project_hr_admin is  an email

Comment: well as i told you, you have to be sure that it's unique. Or create a new model. Here you have 3 projects return for one user : how do you chose, when he will create a team, the good project ?

Comment: Yes a user can have multiple project. a team can be linked to multiple project but a project is attributed to only one team ! What I am trying to do is to link a team to a project.. The user create a project .. then create a team and after the team is created the team is directly linked to the project, I am clear enough . ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154314/discussion-between-bestasttung-and-ben2pop).